# Can you have the same Pokemon with different names

Tags: pokemon

I was thinking about a character in the TV show during one episode of sun and moon Ash meets a trainer who just loves Pikachu and I wanted to make a deck baced on her so I understand you can only have 4 with the same name but what if they had a different name like "Pikachu libre" or "detective Pikachu" or ex and gx

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess this isn't a complete duplicate, but a similar question has an answer here:

[Pokemon cards with the same name and different features](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/47058/pokemon-cards-with-the-same-name-and-different-features)

You can play up to 4 copies of cards with the same name. If they have different names you can play up to 4 copies of each of them in your deck.

Rules text on the rule of playing multiple copies of a card (quoted from a quote in this answer: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/47062/24175):

> **DECK BUILDING**
>
> (...)
>
> Also, except for basic Energy, you can only have 4 cards with the same name in your deck. This means you can have only 4 cards called “Pignite” in your deck, even if they all have different attacks. Finally, your deck must have at least one Basic Pokémon in it.
>
> (...)

If you are wondering what it means to have the same name (quoted from a quote in this answer: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/47062/24175):

> **WHAT DOES AND DOESN’T COUNT FOR A POKÉMON’S NAME?**
>
> • Some Pokémon cards have extra information after their name, such as a Level or a symbol like ***GL***. A Pokémon’s name changes how you can evolve or play certain cards. Level is not part of a Pokémon’s name:
>       ◆ Gengar, Gengar LV. 43, Gengar LV. 44, and Gengar LV.*X* all have the same name
>   • Symbols at the end of a Pokémon’s name are part of a Pokémon’s name:
>       ◆ Alakazam, Alakazam **四**, and Alakazam ☆ all have different names from each other
>       ◆ However, δ (Delta Species) is not part of a Pokémon’s name. Aerodactyl and
>   Aerodactyl δ (Delta Species) have the same name
>   • An owner or form name in a Pokémon’s name is part of the Pokémon’s name:
>       ◆ Meowth, Alolan Meowth, and Rocket’s Meowth have different names
>
> When you are building a deck, you can have only 4 copies of a card with the same name in it, except for basic Energy cards. If your deck has 1 each of Gengar, Gengar LV. 43, Gengar LV. 44, and Gengar LV.*X*, you can’t put any more cards named Gengar in your deck! However, you could have 4 Meowth, 4 Alolan Meowth, and 4 Rocket’s Meowth.