# Can any card named exactly "Pikachu" evolve into "Raichu"?

Tags: pokemon

There are many different pokemon cards named exactly "Pikachu". **(I am not asking about Alolan versions, etc.)** If I have a Raichu card that says "evolves from Pikachu", can I evolve it from any of those different versions?

For example, the original base set and Jungle set both had cards named "Pikachu" with no special modifiers. Are these interchangeable?

Ex:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: No. My question specifically says I am not asking about alolan vs non-alolan. I am asking if for example, the cards named exactly "Pikachu" for example in the original base set and Jungle set are interchangeable for evolution.

Comment: This one is close, but asking about the 4-copy rule, not evolution. https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/47058/pokemon-cards-with-the-same-name-and-different-features

Comment: You are asking about whether the second-stage can come from any first-stage pokemon that has the specified name. The answer to the proposed duplicate is also exactly the answer to this question; the fact that the proposed duplicate was specifically concerned with whether *"Alolan"* changed the name can be considered an example.